# SQL: Exclude only if Row has a value for the same ID

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Requirement:  In a table, if for the same ID, if Only for those RegStatus in (Hardcopies,SoftCopies) if there is a status 'InvalidData' , then include only that row and ignore the rest.
But if for the same ID, if there is no status 'InvalidData' , don't ignore any rows

[image]

```
 with source as (
       select 'ABC' as ID , 'SoftCopies' as RegStatus , 'ValidData' as DocStatus, 'ID of  signatory' as Name
         union all
          select 'ABC' as ID , 'SoftCopies' as RegStatus , 'ValidData' as DocStatus, 'Taxable Status ' as Name
         union all
          select 'ABC' as ID , 'SoftCopies' as RegStatus , 'ValidData' as DocStatus, 'Bank Letter' as Name
         union all
            select 'ABC' as ID , 'SoftCopies' as RegStatus , 'InValidData' as DocStatus, 'Articles of Association' as Name
         union all
            select 'EDG' as ID , 'ABC Pending' as RegStatus , 'ValidData' as DocStatus, 'ID of  signatory' as Name
         union all
          select 'EDG' as ID , 'ABC Pending' as RegStatus , 'ValidData' as DocStatus, 'Questionnaire document' as Name
         union all
          select 'EDG' as ID , 'ABC Pending' as RegStatus , 'ValidData' as DocStatus, 'Trade Register Extract' as Name
         union all
            select 'JFG' as ID , 'Onboarding' as RegStatus , 'ValidData' as DocStatus, 'Questionnaire document' as Name
         union all
            select 'JFG' as ID , 'Onboarding' as RegStatus , 'ValidData' as DocStatus, 'Taxable Status Certificate for GB' as Name
         union all
          select 'JFG' as ID , 'Onboarding' as RegStatus , 'ValidData' as DocStatus, 'Bank Letter' as Name
         union all
          select 'JFG' as ID , 'Onboarding' as RegStatus , 'ValidData' as DocStatus, 'Trade Register Extract' as Name
         union all
            select 'MON' as ID , 'HardCopies' as RegStatus , 'ValidData' as DocStatus, 'Trade Register Extract' as Name
         union all
          select 'MON' as ID , 'HardCopies' as RegStatus , 'InValidData' as DocStatus, 'Trade Register Extract' as Name
         union all
          select 'MON' as ID , 'Onboarding' as RegStatus , 'ValidData' as DocStatus, 'Trade Register Extract' as Name
         union all
          select 'MON' as ID , 'Onboarding' as RegStatus , 'InValidData' as DocStatus, 'Trade Register Extract' as Name
     union all
      select 'XYZ' as ID , 'AcceptanceReview' as RegStatus , 'ValidData' as DocStatus , 'Trade Register Extract' as Name
     union all
      select 'xyz' as ID , 'AcceptanceReview' as RegStatus , 'InValidData' as DocStatus , 'Trade Register Extract' as Name
     union all
         select 'XYZ' as ID , 'PacketSubmitted' as RegStatus , 'ValidData' as DocStatus , 'Trade Register Extract' as Name
       )
     select * from source;
```

[image]

> **UPDATE :Requirement Update as below**

If the RegStatus column shows any without HardCopies or SoftCopies
and has ABC Pending, Then only one entry is required for each unique ID as Example EDG

If the RegStatus column shows any without HardCopies or SoftCopies
or ABC Pending, Then leave it as is it Example JFG

If the ‘RegStatus’ shows:
‘HardCopies’  OR ‘SoftCopies’
Then we need multiple entries for each of the documents under that ID and where the DocStatus status is 'invalid data’.
Example MON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is one way:

```
select * from source
qualify max(case when DocStatus = 'InValidData' and RegStatus in ('HardCopies', 'SoftCopies') then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by ID) = 0 
or DocStatus = 'InValidData'
```

Comment: I need only for those RegStatus is HardCopies or SoftCopies not other status

Comment: @Karthik see updated answer.

Comment: I have updated the original question both query and screenshot , the XYZ rows

Comment: @Karthik ok , see the updated answer

Comment: , I have updated the new requirement in original question , can you please help out on this

Answer (score 3):

Using `QUALIFY` and conditional windowed COUNT:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
QUALIFY 
   COUNT_IF(DocStatus='InValidData' AND RegStatus IN('HardCopies','SoftCopies')) 
           OVER(PARTITION BY ID) = 0 OR DocStatus = 'InValidData';
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I need only for those RegStatus is HardCopies or SoftCopies, not other status , I meant if Regstatus is not HardCopies or SoftCopies and had DocStatus InvalidData  , then just ignore dont do anything

Comment: @Karthik The query could be extended to handle your edit

Comment: I have updated the new requirement in original question , can you please help out on this